# Lua says that these variables are numbers but I can't use them to make a circle in Love2d

Tags: lua, love2d

edit: terrible mistake, just forgot to provide radius lol. Thanks for helping :)

I am so confused by this happening. I'm fairly certain all parts of my code work but for some reason, the `x` and `y` co-ordinates are not being printed by Love2D, despite showing them on screen and using `type()` to show that they're numbers.

```
function love.load()
    window = {}
    window.x, window.y = love.graphics.getDimensions()

    enemies = {}
end

function newenemy()
    x = math.random(0, window.x)
    y = math.random(0, window.y)
    table.insert(enemies, {x = x, y = y, speed = 5})
end

function love.update(dt)
    newenemy()
    for i=#enemies, 1, -1 do
        local angle = math.atan((love.mouse.getY()-enemies[i]['y'])/(love.mouse.getX()-enemies[i]['x']))
        if love.mouse.getX() < enemies[i]['x'] then angle = angle + math.pi end
        enemies[i]['x'] = enemies[i]['x'] + math.cos(angle)*enemies[i]['speed']
        enemies[i]['y'] = enemies[i]['y'] + math.sin(angle)*enemies[i]['speed']
    end
end

function love.draw()
    for i=1, #enemies do 
        love.graphics.print('('..enemies[i]['x']..','..enemies[i]['y']..')')
        love.graphics.circle('fill', enemies[i]['x'], enemies[i]['y'])
    end 
end
```

To show the actual numbers, I've been commenting out the line to draw the circle and watching the numbers change as I move my cursor across the screen. I truly don't know what is going on. This code is from a much larger (~400 lines) script that I'm writing for and I thought there was some error with the variables but it still seems tp occur in 30 lines of code.

```
Error

main.lua:27: bad argument #4 to 'circle' (number expected, got no value)


Traceback

[C]: in function 'circle'
main.lua:27: in function 'draw'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the error

```
main.lua:27: bad argument #4
```

speaks of the *fourth* argument, wherein you are only providing *three*.

The fourth argument to [`love.graphics.circle`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.circle) is the **radius** of the circle.

```
love.graphics.circle('fill', enemies[i]['x'], enemies[i]['y'], 10)
```